# MVC design in iOS View talks to Model - Swift - Programmatically

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a question regarding the MVC design in iOS application.

Suppose that I have set a `UIView` class with this gesture recogniser:

```swift
class CardView: UIView {        
    init(frame: CGRect) {
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(gesture:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture!)
    }
    
    @objc func handlePan(gesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            handleBegan(gesture)
        case .changed:
            handleChanged(gesture)
        case .ended:
            handleEnded(gesture)
            sendDataToDatabase()
        case .cancelled:
            turnCardBackToOrigin()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the target of the view gesture is the view itself.
Now suppose that in  switch `case .ended` I want to send data to database.

Since I'm making View (CardView) talk with the model (Data), would this break the MVC designing rules? Is this code design implementation wrong according to MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it breaks the MVC pattern. Only the Controller should talk to the Model.
Your Controller can act as a `delegate` to the `CardView`.

This is how you could fix it.

```
protocol CardViewDelegate: class {
    func cardViewShouldSendDataToDatabase(_ cardView: CardView)
}

class CardView: UIView{
    weak var delegate: CardViewDelegate?
    
    // ...
    
    func sendDataToDatabase() {
        delegate?.cardViewShouldSendDataToDatabase(self)
    }
}
```

Then you only have to make your Controller conform to the `CardViewDelegate` protocol and implement `cardViewShouldSendDataToDatabase` in which you would talk to the model.

Comment: Also I think one missing step in the process is to set the view ```delegate``` to the controller whenever creating the view in controller

Comment: I don’t agree with this either. `cardViewShouldSendDataToDatabase`? The card view should not even know there _is_ a database. Arguably, the view controller shouldn’t even know.

Comment: How would you do it @matt?

Comment: You can name your delegate method how you want of course, up to you ;)

Comment: The card view should just report what happened. I was tapped! What that _means_ is not view logic.

Comment: So your concern is only about the naming of the protocol's method

Comment: I agree with matt that you should name your methods based on what they do. For example if you're going to dismiss the view when the pan gesture ends you should name it something like `cardViewWillDismiss`